# Dispacter Servelt xml file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am working on project with Spring mvc and i want to use jpa features as well.
I have an 3 entity classes, their corresponding repository interfaces. I have their autowired objects in common service class. However I am facing issues while creating bean for this service class object which is used in controller.
The 3 model class are User, Appointment and Notification.
The repository interface extends CRUDRepository interface.
Service class :

```
@Service

public class EHealthService

{

    @Autowired
    UserRepository uRepo;

    @Autowired
    AppointmentRepository aRepo;

    @Autowired
    NotificationRepository nRepo;

    public void registerUser(User u)
    {
        uRepo.save(u);
    }


    public boolean login(User u)
    {
        if(uRepo.findByemail(u.getEmail())!=null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public List<User> getDoctorList()
    {
        return uRepo.findByisdoctor(true);
    }
   // some more functions

}
```

Controller class:

```
@Controller

public class EHealthController 

{

    @Autowired
    EHealthService eservice;
    //Some code
}
```

ehealth-dispacter-servlet.xml file:

```
<beans 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xsi:schemaLocation=
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.cl3.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.cl3.model" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.cl3.service" />

<bean     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>

    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.cl3.model"/>
</bean>

 <bean id="transactionManager" 
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
<property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
```

```
 <jpa:repositories base-package="com.cl3.model"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cl3" />
    <property name="username" value="ucan" />
    <property name="password" value="ucan" />
</bean>

<bean id="eservice" class="com.cl3.service.EHealthService">
    <property name="uRepo" ref="uRepo"></property>
    <property name="nRepo" ref="nRepo"></property>
    <property name="aRepo" ref="aRepo"></property>
</bean>

  <bean id="uRepo"  class="com.cl3.model.UserRepository">
</bean>
 <bean id="nRepo" class="com.cl3.model.NotificationRepository">
</bean>
<bean id="aRepo"  class="com.cl3.model.AppointmentRepository">
</bean>
```

It says the class is an interface.
What will be the bean for eservice object and to enable jpa in dispacter servel xml file?

Thank you.

Comment: plz copy the stackrace ...and of course the problem/solution is somewhere in your configuration details...

Comment: I have not written any configuration file yet

Comment: ..then i'd recommend one of spring's "getting started"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring xml based configuration then add below bean's to configuration file :

```
 <bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <!-- This makes /META-INF/persistence.xml is no longer necessary -->
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.howtodoinjava.demo.model" />
  <!-- JpaVendorAdapter implementation for Hibernate EntityManager.
       Exposes Hibernate's persistence provider and EntityManager extension interface -->
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
     <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
  </property>
  <property name="jpaProperties">
     <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
     </props>
  </property>
```

```
   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
  <property name="username" value="root" />
  <property name="password" value="password" />
```

```
 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryBean" />
```

Register component scanning by adding this binding annotation in xml file :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.projectname.demo" />
```

If your project is spring mvc the add below binding annotation to xl file

```
 <!-- This allow for dispatching requests to Controllers -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

For declarative transaction management add below piece in xml file.

```
   <tx:annotation-driven />
```

Basically you no need to add service bean in xml configuration file if you are enabled component scanning feature in spring.
Add required dependencies to integrate jpa with spring.
Refer this link will help you more :

https://howtodoinjava.com/jpa/spring-hibernate-jpa-configuration-example/